# Drawing Points in Java

Tags: procedural-generation

first my problem.

I hav an array with 6 Points in mind no x or y is given they wanted to be connected in a predefined way that is also aviable in a Database/Hashmap/Array.

how can i get Java to draw something like a hexagon or even biger structures procedualy ?
[something like this](http://alistapart.com/d/394/shape-points.png)

the key here is that i only know wich points shoud connect java has to determine the length of the conection ...

last thing i will link something how it shoud look realy in the end so you get an idea of the complexity.
[See every circle only as a point for now](http://evemaps.dotlan.net/map/The_Forge#structures)

thx for your help and sorry for my bad english.

---

Edit

ok as i see my Question seems to be not clear enught.

i have 7500 points and 14000 conections.

each conection conects 2 fixed points a point can have multiple connections or only one.
i want to display this but how?

Comment: It sounds like you either need to use an established library - I've used JavaGeom before; http://geom-java.sourceforge.net/ - or you need to design all of this from scratch. Hexagons aren't the problem here - defining how many Points within the Shape you want to represent is. You'd need a matrix to store the set of potential coordinates that's also able to define used coords.

Comment: i kinda know how i will Display it in the end the big Problem for me is how can i calculate the positions of each Point/Line ? how can i get java to look for each connection and thinks how it will be the best in the end ? i know something recursive will be the best but what Algorithm is needed to determine howlong a conection has to be and where the points has to be?

Comment: If you know the width of the hexagon (as an example), and it has equal-length sides, then a side of a hexagon is the width divided by 2. This makes it relatively easy to work out where the rest of the points sit. You'll also need to use `Math.toRadians()` to calculate the angle (360 / 6).

Comment: Create a data type to handle this specific type of shape. Maybe even extend `Shape`. There's no easy answer to this question as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the logic. Hold the data somewhere and display like below example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Polygon p = new Polygon();
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      p.addPoint((int) 
      (100 + 50 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 5)),
      (int) (100 + 50 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 5)));
      g.drawPolygon(p);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("Polygon");
      frame.setSize(350, 250);
      frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
         }
      });
      Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
      contentPane.add(new Main());
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah i can draw a circle with this but i need a complex geometry shape as i edited the question.